# How do I convert $x(-\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ -r }-1 } -1)$ to $\frac { x }{ { 10 }^{ r }-1 } $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I convert the equation 
$$x\left(-\frac { 1 }{ { 10 }^{ -r }-1 } -1\right)$$
into this one:
$$\frac { x }{ { 10 }^{ r }-1 } $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x \left( -\frac{1}{10^{-r}-1}-1 \right)=x \left( - \frac{10^r}{1-10^r}- \frac{1-10^r}{1-10^r} \right)=x \left ( \frac{-10^r-1+10^r}{1-10^r} \right) $$